# How to give description for directory in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I am working with Doxygen to document my project. I know, by using the below Doxygen commands, we can give a description for source files.

```
/**
* \file example.cpp
* \brief Implementation of example functions 
*/
```

Is there any way to give a description for a directory/folder in Doxygen?

Comment: Dd you have a look at the manual chapter regarding "special commands" and in particular the paragraph about \dir?

Comment: sorry , just now i seen definition of "\dir" in Doxygen special commands... Now i can able to give description for directory... thank u @albert

Comment: yes , with the help of Doxygen \dir command , we can provide description for directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`\dir`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmddir) doxygen command. I asked a similar question [how to link to documentation of directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31167724/3154588) in which I show

```
/// \dir cpp/vtutil 
///      
/// \brief Brief description of the dir cpp/vtutil goes here
/// 
/// \details A more detailed description goes here.
```

This works to provide documentation of the directory. In my original question, I was having trouble using `\ref` to link to the directory documentation. After more digging and experimenting I was able to get it to work. I commented in my answer that 
Doxygen is pretty forgiving or flexible with the path used when documenting a directory with the `\dir` command, but it is rather picky when referencing it with the `\ref` command.