# Give directories a brief description in Doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I've used `@file` and `@brief` to give my files happy little brief descriptions in Doxygen, as below:

[image: Doxygen brief documentations]

Now, I would like my directories, such as `common`, shown in the image, to also have happy little brief descriptions. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks to me like a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291663/how-to-give-description-for-directory-in-doxygen

Comment: @albert: I thought about that, but the accepted answer links to another answer which itself talks only about referencing directories from within a file's documentation. I'm interested in setting up brief descriptions (as in the picture I posted), which are not discussed by the aforementioned answers. I'm also interested in knowing where all of this directory-specific documentation goes, which is also unaddressed. So I think it's non-duplicate and, insofar as there is overlap, the existing answers seem incomplete to me.

Comment: The information of the directory has to be in a doxygen parsed fiel. Looks like a possible solution is placing a file with extension .dir in the directory (add it to INPUT or FILTER_PATTERNS), set the EXTENSION_MAPPING to C (dir=c) and place the \dir command etc as  a comment block in this dir file. In the comment block you can place all types of information regarding the directory. The information can be  seen when clicking on the directory name in the shown tree.